How to disable esbuild direct-eval warning
In one of my apps I need the eval function. I search and can't something to replace it. When I upgrade to Angular 19, I have the following Warning in the build-watch and build-prod :
▲ [WARNING] Using direct eval with a bundler is not recommended and may cause problems [direct-eval]

src/frontend/app/statistics/statistics.component.ts:554:14:
      554 │               eval(option['function'] + '(' + cpt + ')');
          ╵               ~~~~

  You can read more about direct eval and bundling here: https://esbuild.github.io/link/direct-eval

Where can I disable this warning ? I didn't find any esbuild config (like eslint) or something
Thanks

You should focus on fixing the warning, rather than silencing it. This is a real issue that the compiler tries to warn you about.

Could you try replacing the eval expression with something like:
this[option['function']](cpt)

we get the string expression from option['function'] which would be a function on this and execute it with the cpt argument.

Thanks for that, I didn't think of it ! I just had to add // @ts-ignore because I have the following error and didn't manage to fix it :/
`
✘ [ERROR] TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'StatisticsComponent'. [plugin angular-compiler]
src/frontend/app/statistics/statistics.component.ts:506:24:
  506 │                         this[option.function](cpt);
      ╵                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

`

@Nathan30 Just test this code once, because eval executes on the global context, but we are executing on component context (this), just double check it, to avoid any bugs caused due to the function not executing

Yes I test it and it's working perfectly :)

@Nathan30 ok then great!
